# How to make computer take random variable each time in pig game

Tags: c++

So here is my code, the problem I am having is that for whatever reason when ever the "dice" is rolled it rolls whatever that number is continously until it reaches the limit I set it up to be.

This is isn't the case for the Human user but it is for computer use. How can i fix this so that the computer will take a random variable between 1-6 each time.

```
int main () 
{
    int humanTurn=0;
    int humanTotalScore=0;
    int computerTotalScore=0;
    int computerTurn=3;
    float diceRoll = 0;
    int score = 0;
    int computerScore = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    int humanScore = 0;
    int pause = 0;
    float computerDiceRoll = 0;

    srand(time(0));

    cout << "Welcome to the game of pig, the first player to reach to 100 wins."<< endl;
    cout << "if you roll a one no score will be recorded and your turn will go the computer"<< endl;
    cout << " If you choose to hold, the total score accumilated will be recorded" << endl;

    while ((humanTotalScore < 100) && (computerTotalScore < 100)) 
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "press 1 to  roll or 2 to save your score: ";
        cin >> answer;

        for (int i=0; i<1; i++) 
        {
            diceRoll = rand() % 6 + 1;
        }

        if ((diceRoll > 1) && ( answer == 1))
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "your  current roll is: " << diceRoll << endl; 
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;

            score += diceRoll;
            cout << "Score for this turn is: " << score << endl;
            cout << "your total score is: " << humanTotalScore << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (answer == 2)
        {
            cout << "your score of: " << score << " will be saved" << endl;
            humanTotalScore += score;
            score = 0;
        } 
        else 
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "you  rolled a ONE. You lose your turn and any points that were with it"   <<endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "enter any key to continue." << endl; // necessary to let user know that there     point were discontinued
            cin >> pause;
            score = 0;
            computerTurn = score;
        }
        if ((computerTurn == 0) || (answer ==2))
        {
            cout << "it is now the Computers turn" << endl;

            for (int i=0; i<1; i++) 
            {
                srand(time(0));
                computerDiceRoll = rand() % 6 + 1;
            }
            while ((computerDiceRoll > 1)&& (computerScore <= 20))
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "computers roll is : " << diceRoll << endl; 
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;

                computerScore += diceRoll;
                computerTotalScore += computerScore;

                cout << "computer current score is : " << computerScore << endl;
                cout << "computer total score is: " << computerTotalScore << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;
                if (diceRoll == 1)
                {
                    computerScore = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I find that for-loop rather limited in its effectiveness.

Comment: so should I just make my for loop as a global function? or do you recommend me doing something else?

Comment: It's good practice to indent your code. It will also make others more inclined to read it :)

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<1; i++) { srand(time(0)); ...` this will happen so fast that the time's unlikely to tick over to a distinct second, so you're using the same seed and restarting the random number sequence at the same value.  Just call `srand` the once near the top of main and never call it again... future calls to `rand` will then be random (or close enough to).

Answer (score 2):

```
'for (int i=0; i<1; i++)'
```

that line is useless.
and this line makes no sense:

```
'while ((computerDiceRoll > 1)&& (computerScore <= 20)){'
```

and at this line:

```
cout << "computers roll is : " << diceRoll << endl;
```

you print the last "human" roll.
your computer roll is at "computerDiceRoll" not in "diceRoll"

Comment: nevermind this problem I believe is fixed now. I have literally spent hours today just trying to solve this problem